# do you need to specify the direction of b for a moderated regression

Tags: regression, interaction, two-tailed-test

I conducted a moderated regression, but didn't specify the direction of moderation by M. that is I didnt specify whether the relationship between X and Y would be greater at lower or higher levels of M.

does that matter? in terms of sample size and power calculations?

my understanding was statistically it doesn't matter because b is test that the regression coefficient is different from zero. it will be -b if one direction and +b if in the other direction. I then probed the interaction at =/- 1sd and found it was at high levels of M the interaction was significant but not at low levels.
An examiner said since I didn't specify the direction of moderation by M caution needs to exercised in interpreting the results. But from my understanding of how moderation works this isn't a valid point..... am I correct?

Comment: If you have an interaction term involving a moderator, then your regression model presumably also includes a coefficient for the moderator itself without the interaction. It's not clear from your question whether the coefficient you are discussing is that for the moderator itself or for the interaction term involving it. It would help if you could show the model in question and edit the question to clarify which coefficient(s) you are asking about.

Comment: thanks- it was with regards to the coefficient for the moderator- I didn't a priori specify whether that would be positive or negative; whether the interaction between X and Y would greater at higher or lower levels of M

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the context of the study and the hypotheses you tested.

In general, the word "moderator" just describes a variable involved in an interaction with the primary predictor of interest. For example, in a linear model with outcome Y, primary predictor X, and moderator M you might write in R:

```
lm(Y ~ X * M),
```

which is then expanded to:

```
lm(Y ~ X + M + X:M).
```

From the model-fitting perspective, there is no distinction between X and M. You get individual coefficient estimates for each (representing its association with outcome when the other is at its reference level or at 0), and an estimate for the coefficient of their interaction (product) term, `X:M`. The overall "significance" of the moderation is then best assessed by the "significance" of the *interaction* coefficient.

If that interaction coefficient is what you have in mind by the "test that the regression coefficient is different from zero" and you had no pre-specified hypothesis about the direction of the moderation, then that's the appropriate test. Estimates of sample size for adequate power would be based on testing whether the value of the interaction coefficient differs from 0.

You also say, however, that you "probed the interaction at +/- 1sd and found it was at high levels of M the interaction was significant but not at low levels." That's a different assessment of "interaction" than the test of the interaction coefficient itself. As you evaluated outcome predictions at different levels of `M`, you necessarily included the coefficient for `M` itself, not just the `X:M` interaction term, in the calculations.

In that context, the "significance" depends on the particular null hypothesis that you tested at the different levels of M. Furthermore, when you perform multiple tests like this, you need to make some adjustments for [multiple comparisons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem). That's a particular type of "caution" in interpreting results.

Although you don't always need to specify a direction for moderation, it's possible to do so; perhaps in your course of study you were expected to. That changes the null hypothesis from the one implicit in the generic interaction model above, and would affect *a priori* sample size and power estimates.